# Windows Variant of the following Linux code

Tags: linux, marklogic

The Following code is working on Linux but with windows bat file it throws an error :

```
curl -X PUT --anyauth -u admin:admin --header "Content-Type:application/json" -d {"range-element-index":[{"scalar-type":"string", "namespace-uri":"", "localname":"userName", "collation":"http://marklogic.com/collation/codepoint", "range-value-positions":true,"invalid-values":"reject"}]} http://localhost:8002/manage/v2/databases/db/properties
```

and the error is as follows :

```
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: namespace-uri
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: localname
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: collation:http
curl: (3) [globbing] unmatched close brace/bracket in column 49
{"errorResponse":{"statusCode":"400", "status":"Bad Request", "messageCode":"XDMP-JSONCHAR", "message":"XDMP-JSONCHAR: xdmp:unquote(\"{range-element-index:[{scalar-type:string,\", (), \"format-json\") -- Unexpected character 's' in JSON at line 1 char 36"}}
```

Comment: don't have access to a Windows box to try it, but you need to escape something, probably either square or curly brackets.

Comment: Have you considered putting the payload in a file?

Comment: try https://git-for-windows.github.io/ it has a very good bash shell

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed, the issue is likely the fact that the rest payload needs to be quoted.

There are various places in the ML guides that show windows versions of commands (such as for MLCP).

As an example of your challenge - and what looks  like the solution, please see the conversation at the bottom of this page - including screen-shots of a cUrl command on windows:

https://developer.marklogic.com/learn/rest/setup